# How can I set signing order by using DocusignApi

Tags: java, docusignapi

I want to set the signing order in an embedded signing envelope, which means that I have 2 recipients that sign the document one by one. On the sandbox UI that I can tick the checkbox to set the signing order and have 2 recipients there. The second one receives the email after the first one finished. I am wondering how can I implement the same logic by code.

I ve already tried to set the routing order but not what I want.

```
TemplateRole signer = new TemplateRole();
signer.setEmail(signerEmail);
signer.setName(signerName);
signer.clientUserId(String.valueOf(xxx));
signer.setRoleName("signer");
signer.setRoutingOrder("1");

TemplateRole signer1 = new TemplateRole();
signer1.setEmail("xxx");
signer1.setName("xxx");
signer1.clientUserId(String.valueOf(123));
signer1.setRoleName("signer1");
signer1.setRoutingOrder("2");

envelopeDefinition.setTemplateRoles(Arrays.asList(signer, signer1));
```

This is what I want:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUyFy.png)

Not this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GtfC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if you're referencing a template you'll need to set up the routing order there. When using using TemplateRoles, it's not necessary to set the routing order in the signer definition.

Second, in your code you're hitting signer.setRoutingOrder() twice, looks like you left the 1 off the second reference.

Third, I don't believe "0" is a valid position in the routing order. Try 1 & 2 instead.

Comment: Hi Drew, you are right that I made some mistakes in the code. I have another question that related to 2 recipients sign on the same doc, it is here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57098241/send-embedded-signing-email-with-setting-signing-order). Wondering if you have any idea there?