# Send embedded signing email with setting signing order

Tags: java, docusignapi

So basically I need to use embedded signing feature to get the URL and embed into my application, and then my customer can sign the document from my side. Apart from that, after my customer signed on the doc, he needs to ask his debtor to sign on the same doc as well.
So on DocuSign UI, I found that I can set a signing order, which means the second recipient receives the email right after the first recipient signed (perfect match my requirement).
[setting on UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQtVw.png)
However, the second recipient can not receive the email after the first signer signed even though on UI it says sent.

```
public Envelope embeddedSigning(Long debtorId, String signerEmail, String signerName, String templateId) throws ApiException, IOException {
    // create an envelop
    EnvelopeDefinition envelope = makeEnvelope(debtorId, signerEmail, signerName, templateId);

    ApiClient apiClient = baseRestApiClient();
    apiClient.addDefaultHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + getToken());
    EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(apiClient);
    EnvelopeSummary summary = envelopesApi.createEnvelope(accountId, envelope);
    RecipientViewRequest viewRequest = makeRecipientViewRequest(debtorId, signerEmail, signerName);
    ViewUrl viewUrl = envelopesApi.createRecipientView(accountId, summary.getEnvelopeId(), viewRequest);

    // @formatter:off
    return Envelope.builder()
        .envelopId(summary.getEnvelopeId())
        .redirectUrl(viewUrl.getUrl()).build();
    // @formatter:on
  }
```

```
private EnvelopeDefinition makeEnvelope(Long debtorId, String signerEmail, String signerName, String templateId) throws IOException {
    EnvelopeDefinition envelopeDefinition = new EnvelopeDefinition();
    envelopeDefinition.setEmailSubject("Please sign this document");
    envelopeDefinition.setTemplateId(templateId);

    TemplateRole signer = new TemplateRole();
    signer.setEmail(signerEmail);
    signer.setName(signerName);
    signer.clientUserId(String.valueOf(debtorId));
    signer.setRoleName("signer0");
    signer.setRoutingOrder("1");

    TemplateRole signer1 = new TemplateRole();
    signer1.setEmail("xxx");
    signer1.setName("xxx");
    signer1.clientUserId(String.valueOf(xxx));
    signer1.setRoleName("signer1");
    signer1.setRoutingOrder("2");

    envelopeDefinition.setTemplateRoles(Arrays.asList(signer, signer1));
    envelopeDefinition.setStatus("sent");
    return envelopeDefinition;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting `signer1.clientUserId(String.valueOf(xxx));` which means you are making signer an embedded signer. By Default, DocuSign does not send email to the embedded signer. By making a signer as embedded signer, you are telling DocuSign that calling App will take care of deciding when to host signing ceremony for this signer so DocuSign will not send an email as they will not be doing signing from the email, instead it be your App which will be generating Signing URL when that signer is on your App. So if you remove `signer1.clientUserId(String.valueOf(xxx));` code then you will see that signer1 will get an email from DocuSign.

[Docs](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/concepts/embedding) has more details about embedded signing.

Answer (score 0):

Typically routing order starts at 1. so it should be 1 and 2, not 0 and 1.
Apart from that, "Sent" is the status for the entire envelope. The envelope goes to routing order 1 first. Then, when all recipients of routing order 1 finished signing, it goes to 2 etc. I'm not sure if you actually have an issue here, but please confirm after you changed to 1 and 2 what exactly do you see that you don't expect.

Comment: Hi I tried your suggestion but still, the second recipient cannot receive the email. I changed status to something else like 'created', no luck BTW. I basically need 2 recipients to sign on the same doc, do you know any other way that I can have a try? Thanks in advance.

Comment: second recipient will only receive the email after the first one signed. Did the first recipient sign? and the second recipient did not receive an email?

Comment: Yes, the first signer signed the doc, the second guy still didn’t receive it

Comment: did you check and double check the email address? did you have them check their spam folder?

Comment: in the above code I see "xxx" for second signer but I do see signerEmail variable for the first one. so I wonder about that.

Comment: Hi I am pretty sure that I used correct email and also checked junk folder. The `xxx` there was my hard coding email, just a replacement, or you mean signer email and signer1 email should be the same?? is it possible that I use a embedded signing there?

Comment: can I suggest you try to do this first via the web application, not using API, just to see you get the behavior you expect in there? this would isolate if this is an API issue or the system is just not working as you expect